How to only minify, not compile, with SWC?
What is the option, or are the options, for SWC in order not to compile? I only want to use the minifier. I'm bundling with Rollup and I came across this plugin, rollup-plugin-swc-minify, but it sets hardcoded options that I don't want.
I am new to this supermarket of JavaScript packages and packaging, thus new to SWC too. I assume this there is a simple way to do this - though the readme for that rollup plugin makes it sound complicated. Regardless, I haven't been able to figure it out from the SWC docs so far.
I could fork that plugin and change the options, but I'd rather switch to the official @rollup/plugin-swc, which I assume allows me to use a .swcrc file for configuration.
